# How to conditionally assign values to multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

```
#T.shape=(10L,1L)
C=np.zeros((len(T),4)) 
C[T==label1]==[1,1,1,1]
C[T==label2]==[2,2,2,2]
```

Got the error:

> boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

I intend to assign the 4 values on the right side of the "=" to each row of `C` based on the corresponding T value.  How can I do that?

Comment: Should `cols` be `C`?

Comment: yes,  sorry.  will update

Comment: Try `C[T.ravel() == label1, :] = [1,1,1,1]`

Comment: Paul, it worked.  Thank you.  -Jess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `numpy.where` can do just that.

```
T = np.array([['A','B','A','A'],['B','C','A','B']])
C = np.zeros(T.shape)
C[np.where(T == 'A')] = 1
print(C)
```

should print

```
[[1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```